# Proving the set $E(f) = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ z > f(x,y) \}$ is open if $f$ is continuous.

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta, open-map

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function. I want to prove the set $E(f)$ given by

$E(f) = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ z > f(x,y) \}$

is open.

What I have tried so far:

- Suppose $E(f) = \emptyset$, then obviously $E(f)$ is open.
- If $E(f) \neq \emptyset$, let $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x \in E(f)$ be arbitrary.
  Now we need to show $\exists_{R>0}: B(x,R) \subset E(f)$, where $B(x,R)$ denotes the open sphere around the point $x$ with radius $R$, that is; $B(x,R) = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ |y - x| < R \}$.

  We have that $f$ is continuous, thus $\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\exists_{\delta > 0}\forall_{y \in D(f)}: |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

  Somehow I should be able to pick a $R>0$ (depending on some other variables) such that for any $p \in B(x,R)$, I can show that $p_z > f(p_x, p_y)$ using the definition above. I have had a few attempts at this, without any success unfortunately.

  I also tried creating a closed rectangle around the point $(x_1,x_2)$ and using the fact that $f$ will have a maximum and minimum in this rectangle, given $f$ is continuous. However; this did not seem to work out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region is the inverse image of the open set $(0,\infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ under the continuous function $g(x,y,z) := z-f(x,y)$.

Comment: That is certainly a better way to look at the problem! But do you also know a way to solve the problem using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ criterion?

Comment: Let $P_0 = (x_0, y_0, z_0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be a point such that $\epsilon := g(P_0) = z_0-f(x_0,y_0) > 0$ and let $\delta > 0$ be such that $|g(P) - g(P_0)| < \epsilon$ when $|P-P_0| < \delta$.  Then the ball $|P-P_0| < \delta$ is an open ball containing $P_0$ and contained in the desired region.